# Getting data from php into AJAX success,

Tags: php, ajax

Could I please request some samples how to put my recieved date into my success so I can insert it into one particular div.

The information received from my php while loop

```
{"num":1,"690":{"notification_id":"690","notification_content":"Lucy  Botham posted a status on your
 wall","notification_throughurl":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=565","notification_triggeredby"
:"85","notification_status":"1"}}
```

My dic I need to put it inside with the id of the notification - #notif_ui"+notification_id

I've tried the below but the div hasn't updated

```
success: function(data){
$("#notif_ui"+notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_text">'+data['notification_id']+'</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to change this:

```
$("#notif_ui"+notification_id)
```

to

```
$("#notif_ui"+data.notification_id)
```

Wait, actually, just saw

```
"690":{"notification_id":"690"
```

All your data is under a key that you don't seem to know yet (690), so it makes it a little tricky.  You could do it like this:

```
success: function(data){
    var notification_id;
    for (var i in data) {
        if (i != "num") {
            notification_id = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    $("#notif_ui"+notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_text">'+notification_id+'</div>');
}
```